# Get view in a new instance fragment returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have `ListView.OnItemClickListener` when item click it call function `selectItem()` where i create a new instance of fragment

```
private void selectItem(int position, String groupId) {

     some code
     .......

    // Create a new fragment
    Fragment _fragment = MainGroupFragment.newInstance(mActivity, MainGroupId, groupId);

    View _view = _fragment.getView();//this return null

    ........
    some code
}
```

Code `MainGroupFragment`

```
public class MainGroupFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = "MainGroupFragment";
public static final String ARG_STRING_MAIN_GROUP = "main_group_id";
public static final String ARG_STRING_ITEM_GROUP = "item_group";
public static final String ARG_STRING_ARR_IMAGES = "images";
private Random mRandom;
private static final SparseArray<Double> sPositionHeightRatios = new SparseArray<Double>();
private DisplayImageOptions options;
StaggeredGridView lStaggeredView;
ArrayList<String> lImageUrls = null;
private View lView;

public static final MainGroupFragment newInstance(Activity mActivity, String pMainGroup, String pGroupId){
    MainGroupFragment _fragment = new MainGroupFragment();

    Bundle _bundle = new Bundle();
    _bundle.putString(MainGroupFragment.ARG_STRING_MAIN_GROUP, pMainGroup);
    ArrayList<String> _images = null;
    _images = ItemORM.selectImagesByGroup(mActivity, pGroupId);
    _bundle.putStringArrayList(MainGroupFragment.ARG_STRING_ARR_IMAGES, _images);
    _fragment.setArguments(_bundle);


    return _fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mRandom = new Random();
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_img_placeholder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_img_not_available)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_img_broken)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //@TODO create gridview here
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_main_group_grid, container, false);
    lStaggeredView = (StaggeredGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    lImageUrls = args.getStringArrayList(ARG_STRING_ARR_IMAGES);
    String _groupName = args.getString(ARG_STRING_ITEM_GROUP);

    View _rooHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_main_group_grid_item_header_footer, container, false);
    TextView _header = (TextView) _rooHeader.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
    _header.setText(_groupName);

    lStaggeredView.addHeaderView(_header);
    lStaggeredView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

    setFragmentView(rootView);

    return rootView;

}

..... 
some code
}
```

when i get the view from the newly created fragment it return null. am i doing it wrong? im new and still exploring. any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: I highly recommend you read an actual book about Android instead of scattered tutorials, for example Reto Meier's Professional Android App Development. It would explain better the core concepts of Android framework, including what is causing your confusion (Fragment's lifecycle).

Comment: Who ever is downvoting, take a second to explain why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments do not create their views until they are attached to a Fragment Activity. That is when onCreateView is called.

Familiarise yourself with the fragment life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: is there any way i can create fragment without showing UI? just to get the view?

Comment: What I mean is, whatever you are trying to do is not the normal way to do it. I've never had the need to create but not show a fragment.

Comment: I created a SlidingTabLayout and ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and i want to replace a fragment in the same tab. example im in TAB 1 with Fragment 1 and i want to change the Fragment 1 with Fragment 2 when i click a Navigation Drawer.

Comment: Ok, but why do you need access to the view? Look up replacing a fragment.

Comment: ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.pager);


FragmentStatePagerAdapter a = (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) pager.getAdapter();


 ViewGroup _vGroup = (ViewGroup)lFragmentManager.getFragments().get(pager.getCurrentItem()).getView();
 
 
_vGroup.removeView(_vGroup.findViewById(R.id.grid_view));


_vGroup.addView(THIS_VIEW_FROM_NEW_FRAGMENT);

  
pager.removeViewAt(pager.getCurrentItem());


pager.addView(_vGroup, pager.getCurrentItem());


for this i remove the current item and add the new one.